# Better configuring my firewall for Minecraft

Tags: firewall, minecraft, denial-of-service

Not long ago I purchased a new server, and I'm planning on running a Minecraft server on it.

Now I'm trying to better configure my firewall to stop DDoS attacks on my server while running the Minecraft server.

So my questions regarding this issue are:

1. Can I block all SYN packets?
2. Can I block all UDP packets?
3. Are there any other specific rules I can set on my firewall so it can improve its performance against DDoS attacks?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I block all SYN packets?

Goodness no. SYN is used for TCP, and Minecraft uses TCP.

> Can I block all UDP packets?

If you're running no services that use it, yes; Minecraft doesn't use it by default.

> Are there any other spacific rules I can set on my firewall so it can improve its performances against ddos attacks?

The defaults of `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` is good 99% of the time. The rest of the time you'll need to call your upstream provider anyway, since you won't really be able to do much about it.